# Adding a 1d numpy array to a specifc row of a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array

```
a = np.ones((5, 5))
```

that looks like this

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

and then another array

```
b = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

and I am struggling to find a piece of code in Numpy documentation that would add array b to the specific row in array a

for example I would like to add array b only to the 3rd row of array a so that

```
c = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    [1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: `a[3,:] += b` might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Use this:**

```
a[2] += b
```

**Output:**

```
print (a)
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 2. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

If you don't want to modify `a`, and want the result in a different array `c`, it's best done as a two step process:

```
c = np.copy(a)
c[2] += b
```